# Kotlin LocalDateTime doesn't contain milliseconds attribute

Tags: kotlin

so I have list of times in string like this `2020-03-25T23:58:20.000000647`.
I can parse them to Kotlin `LocalDateTime` like this:

```
val date = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-03-25T23:58:20.000000647")
```

I can get hours or minutes or even nano seconds from `date` like this:

```
println(it.date.hour)
println(it.date.minute)
println(it.date.second)
println(it.date.nanosecond)
```

but there is no `date.millisecond`!
so the question is how can I get milliseconds from Kotlin `LocalDateTime`?

Comment: Take `date.nanosecond` and divide by a million?

Answer (score 1):

**Doesn’t work** for time from kotlinx.datetime as requested by the author

```
date.get(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND)
```

Comment: Kotlin LocalDateTime doesn't have `get()` function

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I misread it.